# Can't figure out how to indent with the packages

Tags: packages, indentation, preamble

I'm trying to write my personal statement, and I used some new packages to format it. I can't figure out why it won't let me indent the paragraphs. I've tried `\par`, `\hspace`, etc, but I've had no luck. Below I've posted the preamble and what the beginning of the statement looks like.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{fontspec}                   
    \usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} 
    \RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[big]{layaureo} 
    \usepackage{titlesec}   
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \setlength\parindent{24pt}

    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
    \setmainfont[
    SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
    BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
    ]
    {Fontin.otf}


    \titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in} 

    \begin{document}
    %Beginning of the statement
    \begin{doublespace}
    \normalsize
    This is the first sentence of the personal statement. 
    \end{doublespace}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, with a little changing of the order of calling packages and adding some text and a section I see indentiation ...

Please see the following MWE (please see I commented your used font I have not installed):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} 
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % <==========================================??
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
    %\setmainfont[
    %SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
    %BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
    %ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
    %]
    %{Fontin.otf}


    \titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}


\begin{document}
    %Beginning of the statement
\section{Test}
\blindtext 

\begin{doublespace}
\normalsize
This is the first sentence of the personal statement. 
\end{doublespace}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

the following result:

[image]

Please see that package `hyperref` should be called last in your case ...